# undefined method `rescue_responses' for ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my ruby 2.3.1, I get this error:

```
 => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/will_paginate-3.0.pre2/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:15:in `block in <class:Railtie>': uninitialized constant WillPaginate::Railtie::Forbidden (NameError)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/bistipweb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
        from /home/bistipweb/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/bistipweb/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/bistipweb/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My `railtie.rb` is:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/collection'

module WillPaginate
        class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
                initializer "will_paginate.active_record" do |app|
                        if defined? ::ActiveRecord
                                require 'will_paginate/finders/active_record'
                                WillPaginate::Finders::ActiveRecord.enable!
                        end
                end

                initializer "will_paginate.action_dispatch" do |app|
                        if defined?(ActionController::Base)
                                config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.update('ActionController::Forbidden'=>Forbidden)
                        end
                 end

                initializer "will_paginate.action_view" do |app|
                        require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view'
                        ActionView::Base.send(:include, WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::ActionView)
                end
         end
end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `ActionDispatch::ShowExeptions` should be `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` (you're missing a `c`)

Comment: Please check my edited question

Comment: This API has been deprecated since rails 3.x: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/activescaffold/132j43c9gq/actiondispatch-showexceptions-rails-upgrade-2-3-x-to-3-2-x

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: ...as it says in the error message - `Please configure your exceptions using a railtie or in your
application config instead. (called from ApplicationController at
/home/app/demo/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31)`

Comment: Umm... can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add any initializer codes for hooking `will_paginate` into Rails project, if you are using recent `will_paginate` versions.

I see you are using `3.0.pre2` version, update it to `3.0.7` in your Gemfile, `bundle update will_paginate` and remove all the codes you added in `railtie.rb`, I think everything would be ok.

Comment: This sounds more sensible, can you give me original `railtie.rb` file? I didn't take a backup before modifying `railtie.rb`. My bad :(

Comment: Just remove codes for module WillPaginate in your railtie.rb. I think after removal that file would be empty if you don't have any other added codes. If so, just remove the file.

Comment: so you want me to delete whole code in `railtie.rb`?

Comment: If you railtie.rb is just about will_paginate, yes, it's ok to delete the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
initializer "will_paginate.action_dispatch" do |app|
  if defined?(ActionController::Base)
    config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.update('ActionController::Forbidden'=>Forbidden)
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried.... got error like this which is same: `uninitialized constant WillPaginate::Railtie::Forbidden (NameError)
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the feature, but it seems that you read a very old documentation to implement, I suggest you read up on how to do this in a more recent documentation...

Comment: Can you provide me link to most recent documentation?

Comment: As I said - I'm not familiar with the feature, so... no, I don't know where is the most recent documentation

Answer (score -2):

I do not find any reason for you to add railtie.rb file. I believe just adding the gem and using it in your view should work.

Comment: yeah... but version of `will_paginate` is also important. I'm using rails 4.2.6 and need to add suitable version of `will_paginate`. So updating from `3.0.pre2` to `3.0.7` as suggested by Larry Lv might work

Comment: Yeah I know...I did not say the version of gem does not matter...I just said the rb file is not require...